# VIM VTreeExplorer plugin (IDE style browsing for VIM)

Tags: vim, plugins, project

I've looked at a number of the IDE style file explorer / management plugins for VIM.  The most popular one seems to be Project,  but I've never got on well with it.  Specifically, having to always create a .project file for the files you want to browse, and that changes to that file hierarchy outside of VIM are not picked up.

I stumbled across the [VTreeExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=184) plugin and I really like the way it works.  I'm trying to work out how I can make it work in a more IDE style way, for instance, to always open vertically down the full length of my window, and once I've opened a file from it, it automatically hides the VTreeExplorer buffer again?  Also, ideally it wouldn't show up when I use :bn or a buffer explorer to tab through each file buffer.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: usually you want the explorer to hide when you are done with it so you have more room to edit text. just bind it to ,b or something and open it only when you need it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658)? It is really good, one of the best file tree plugin for vim available.

Comment: NERDTree looks great, and solves that problem (with a NERDTreeToggle), thanks!